# What is the difference between segments(from segmentation) and classes( from Hierchical Clustering)

Tags: r, image-segmentation, hclust

I am working on meanshift segmentation using R! I am now abit confused!my first question is how I can cluster the segmentation file( defining each segment as a super pixel) and second how I can then define that how many objects and how many classes I have! Because when I do clustering, there are many neighbour segments that are in one class so I cant count them as many segments and they are one segment? right? please someone help!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation assigns each pixel a "segment id", usually with the proviso that all segments by physically contiguous. Hierarchical clustering clusters based on a similarity value. You'll need to write your own function, but it can be quite simple - just take mean rgb values and get distance between them. However you also need to return infinite distance for segments which are not physically contiguous, if you keep the segmentation crieterion.

I'm not familiar with R's hierarchical clustering functions, but it will certainly have one which accepts an arbitrary distance function.

Comment: Thank you very much Malcolm McLean :)